# Is it possible to pull all opportunities related to single contact via contact roles in a Visualforce email template?

Tags: visualforce, email-template, query, opportunitycontactrole

We are trying to compile a broker report detailing commissions on a per broker basis (one email per broker). A single broker may be linked to multiple opportunities via the opportunity's contact roles i.e. the broker may appear on multiple opportunity pages as "Referral Source" under the opportunity's contact roles.

We'd like to set up an email template that displays a list of all the opportunities that the contact is listed as "Referral Source" in the contact roles.

I think that we can query for a list of opportunities that the broker is related to using the following advice: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008zWVIAY

However, I am unsure how to incorporate that into the Visualforce email template below. We are looking to have a table listing all of the broker's referred opportunities along with the related financials in the email.

Any help is appreciated and thanks so much for y'alls time.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Broker Report" recipientType="Contact"   relatedToType="Opportunity">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
<html>
<body>
<STYLE type="text/css">
TH {font-size: 11px; font-face: arial; background: #CCCCCC;
border-width: 1; text-align: center}
TD {font-size: 11px; font-face: verdana}
TABLE {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
TR {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
</STYLE>
<font face = "arial" size="2">
<p>Dear , </p>
<p>Below is a detail of your commission report for this month. </p>
<table border="0">
<tr >
<th>Client</th>
<th>Purchases</th>
<th>Collections</th>
<th>Fees Earned</th>
</tr>
<apex:repeat var="ox" value = "{!relatedTo.Account}">
<tr>
<td>{!ox.Name}</td>
<td>{!ox.Factor_Data__r.Purchase_MTD__c}</td>
<td>{!ox.Factor_Data__r.Collections__c}</td>
<td>{!ox.Factor_Data__r.Earned_Fees__c}</td>
</tr>
</apex:repeat>
</table>
<p />
</font>
</body>
</html>
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the OpportunityContactRoles relationship:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Test" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Opportunity">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
<apex:repeat value="{!recipient.OpportunityContactRoles}" var="contactRole">
  You are related to the following opportunities:
  <apex:outputText rendered="{!contactRole.Role='Referral Source'}">
    {!contactRole.Opportunity.Name} - {!contactRole.Opportunity.Amount}
  </apex:outputText>
</apex:repeat></messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Adjust the merge fields to suit your preferences.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I made some adjustments and am being hit with the following error message: [Error: Unknown property 'core.email.template.EmailTemplateComponentController.contactRole']. Would you happen to know a workaround for this? I should say that I am certainly not qualified to be doing this, so I may be missing something rather apparent. Thanks.

Comment: @Conner contactRole should be whatever value you placed in apex:repeat or apex:dataTable's var attribute. Copy my example code directly and start from there.

Comment: Never mind, I was missing something obvious. However, when I save the template, the plain text preview is simply a display of the code.

Comment: @Conner Yes, that's expected. Use the Merge and Send Test button to view a live preview.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. I've gone ahead with that and it is asking for the 'OpportunityContactRole ID'. I've inputted the 'Contact ID' pulled from a report that is related to the contact I selected, but am receiving an error message stating that the ID is invalid.

Comment: @Conner I would expect that it needs a contact ID and Opportunity Id, not the opportunity contact role Id. Try using those two values instead.

Comment: That's what I assumed as well, but neither are working. The layout requires to select a "Recipient Record" and "Related To Record". The first allows the selection of a specific contact or contact ID, while the latter requires manual input of "OpportunityContactRole ID".

Comment: @Conner Huh, okay. I created a template in my dev org. Let me check.

Comment: Sounds groovy. The help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Conner Double-check your relatedToType. This is working in my dev org as expected. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: If some of the financials were linked to a custom object on the opportunity's related account page, could I use the same format, but reference the API for the fields on the custom object?

Comment: @Conner Is it a parent or child object?

Comment: The custom object is a child object on the account page.

Comment: @Conner Nope, you'd have to write some Apex Code at that point, then, or something equally convoluted. There are limits to what you can do with standard relationship queries.